# Are $S^1$ and $O_2(\mathbb{R})$ isomorphic?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, linear-groups

Let $S^1 = \{z \in \mathbb{C} | |z| = 1\}$ and $O_2(\mathbb{R}) = \{A \in GL_2(\mathbb{R})|A^TA = I_2 \}$. Is the group $(S^1, \cdot)$ isomorphic to $(O_2(\mathbb{R}), \cdot)$? Prove it.

This is a question from "Prova Extramuros (2013)", a exam from Brazil. This question asks which of the options are isomorphisms. I easily found the correct option, but in this one I had a little trouble in proving that there was no isomorphism. I interpreted $(S^1, \cdot)$ as a rotation group and $(O_2(\mathbb{R}),\cdot)$ as a rotation and reflection group, so they could not be isomorphic. Is this reasoning correct? Is there a way to prove it more rigorously?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: What have you tried? Alternatively, what is the context behind this problem; where did you find it, and what relevant knowledge do you have? I suggest you read [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) about what you are expected to do when you ask a question on this site. Questions that offer no context or work shown tend to get downvoted and closed, which I imagine you would like to avoid.

Comment: Hint: orthogonal matrices can be written in a certain form.

Comment: @Bernardo $S^1$ is abelian but $O_2(\Bbb R)$ is not, so the two groups are not isomorphic.

Comment: @Bernardo Your statement "one is a rotation group and the other is a rotation and reflection group" is not enough justification. You have only stated that the groups are superficially different, but not that they have enough of a difference for us to know that they are not isomorphic.

Answer (score 3):

$S^1$ has exactly one element of order $2$: namely $-1$.

$O_2(\Bbb R)$ has at least three: $-I$ and two others formed by changing the sign of exactly one diagonal entry.

Since an isomorphism preserves orders, the two cannot be isomorphic.